# Unable to add Microsoft.AspNetCore package to the class library project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, class-library

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 project which has a reference from a shared class library project. In my shared class library, I have a method which access a `webApplication` object as argument.

The problem is that this class is part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` package and I could not find this package in nuget package manager to add my shared class library project.

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) which metioned

> To reference ASP.NET Core, add the following 
> element to your project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And I create a Class Library and test it.

[image]
[image]